# AISC 360 vs AISC 341

Tags: civil-engineering, steel, aisc

I have been trying to determine the response coefficients for seismic analysis of Non building structures in **ASCE 7-10** and found that the value of ***R, the response coefficient***, is larger in case steel connections are detailed using **AISC-341** than **AISC-360**, this would imply a larger design load in case of AISC 341 than AISC 360.

So basically,

```
AISC 341 -> Large seismic design load
AISC 360 -> Smaller seismic design load
```

Does that imply AISC 341 design results in a more conservative steel connection than AISC 360 or is there a difference in steel design philosophy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R-factor reduces seismic design force from the linear-elastic demand. Thus, the *larger* the R-factor, the *lower* the seismic design force.

Essentially, we're approximating inelastic seismic design by accounting for the ductility of the structural system. Connections designed per AISC-360 (which does not specifically address seismic design) can be expected to be less ductile than those designed per AISC-341.

So.

AISC-341 = more ductile = higher R = lower seismic design force

AISC-360 = less ductile = lower R = higher seismic design force

Answer (score 0):

I think that it should be like this:

AISC-341 = more ductile = lower R = higher seismic design force

AISC-360 = less ductile = higher R = lower seismic design force